# SABRE Hotel Passive Segment API

Tags: sabre

In SABRE just started on a "webapp" in SABRE for the agent to convert a HK segment to a passive segment (GK). I am new to the API's. Is there an API for does this with SABRE. I couldn't find one but surely there's a generic method for sending a "valid sabre command" ...

The agent entry would be like this...
0HHTAAGK1DFWIN27JUL-OUT2AUG/HI AIRPORT WEST/SGLB/75.00/SI-@5827 OCEAN DRIVE¥MIAMI FL 38834¥PHONE305-
555-1111@RQNEAR POOL/CF89732901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm transitioning from sabre script writing to sabre red apps.

I found this example/sample it has textboxes to collect information and then push to sabre. You should be able to rename some of the boxes and add some textboxes to collect all the hotel data and push to sabre.

Location: C:\SDK\red-app-sdk-3.0-20.11.6\samples
File: com.sabre.redapp.example3.web.customworkflow-1.0.5-SNAPSHOT-v20201016-1358.zip

This is the main processor file that initiates the data in html, to ts, to sabre.
C:\SDK\workspace\com-sabre-test3-web-module\src\code
**Main.ts**

The modal shown in sabre comes from template dir. These are HTML pages with boxes/drop downs etc.
C:\SDK\workspace\com-sabre-test3-web-module\src\templates
**PnrView.html**

Transmit to sabre
C:\SDK\workspace\com-sabre-test3-web-module\src\code\view
**Pnr.View.ts**

Comment: Thanks folks. I'll look at that one. I've been through about 6-7 of the examples so far and I'm working up the solution right now with a NativeSabreCommand but I'll explore how that one differs and share my findings. Thank you. Certainly interesting learning all this stuff compared to regular scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to convert an HK reservation to GK, as HK is an online sale with the hotel and GK is an offline sale with the hotel.
In order for you to sell a hotel segment in any status, you can use the services listed below according to your needs:

- HotelResModifyLLSRQ: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/hotel/book/Modify_Hotel_Reservation
- EnhancedHotelBookRQ: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/hotel/book/enhanced_hotel_book
- OTA_HotelResLLSRQ: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/hotel/book/book_hotel_reservation

All of these services allow you to sell a hotel with HK or GK status.

Comment: Yeah, technically we know you can't convert a HK to GK, but what we do is "XK" out the "HK" segment and then add the passive segment. I will look through these SOAP calls to see if one can better handle as right now I'm doing it by a native sabre command call which isn't ideal. Thank you. I've also emailed RedApp support to see if they can help me discern how the new "add passive segment" is being done in the recent release. It uses...ReservationModifyRq and I'm learning how to navigate the dev studio but it is passing the PassiveSegmentModifyCollection. Not sure where to find that one.

Comment: When you receive a status = "XK, HX" you must cancel this segment and if it is the case, resell it with the status = "GK" and for that you must do the following flow:
1. GetReservationRQ: You must retrieve the PNR
2. OTA_CancelLLSRQ: cancel the segment with the status equal to XK
3. EnhancedHotelBookRQ: Sell the new segment with the status = "GK" using the service